# Passing current or updated text field tag value for update button?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a table in which I am loading values from the session.

I am working on the update button. I want to pass the current value of the text field to the controller to perform the update operation.

My code looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200">Name</th>
      <th width="150">Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th width="150">Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <% grand_total = 0 %>
    <% session[:cart].each do |key, item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item[:name] %></td>
      <td>Rs. <%= item[:price] %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag(:quantity, item[:quantity]) %>
        <%= link_to("Update", {:action => "update", :id => item[:id], :quantity => item[:quantity]}) %>
      </td>
      <td><%= item[:total_cost] %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to("X", {:action => "delete", :id => item[:id]}) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% grand_total = grand_total + item[:total_cost] %>
    <% end %>
  </thead>
</table>
```

When I hover over the update button, the path shows "localhost:3000/cart?quantity=1" even though I change the value in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

ERB templates are rendered by Rails on the server side, but this interaction is occurring on the client side, in the browser.

`<%= ... %>` is a fancy form of string interpolation, but you can still pretty much think of it the same way:

```
quantity = 1
message = "You have #{quantity} items"
quantity = 2
puts message # -> You have 1 items
```

You wouldn't really expect that to print `You have 2 items`, would you?

Your easiest option is to put some javascript in the `onchange` directive on the text input that will update the submit button, but you might also want to look into "data-binding" if you encounter this problem a lot.

Comment: Ask as a separate question; put a link here, then come back later and delete the comment.